# Writing APL formulas without parens

Tags: syntax, parentheses, apl

I am an APL beginner, 
How to convert,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtD2Z.png]

without using parens?

Comment: It would help if you specified which dialect of APL you use, e.g. APL2, Dyalog APL, GNU APL, NARS2000, etc.

Comment: @practronix512 i'm not sure stackoverflow supports LaTeX. can i edit your question and upload an image in addition to the formula?

Comment: but I used the mathjax tutorial instructions. (was tedious with phone though. )  editing help is appriciated.

Comment: @practronix512 Stack Exchange has enabled MathJax for specific sites, not for the entire network. Stack Overflow does *not* have MathJax enabled. In any case, you indented your MathJax code so it becomes a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpreted your TeX correctly, you want to know if it's possible to remove parens from

```
      (1÷2)*.5
0.7071067812
```

That is doable using the [commute-operator ⍨](https://help.dyalog.com/17.1/Content/Language/Primitive%20Operators/Commute.htm):

```
      .5*⍨1÷2
0.7071067812
```

If `f` is a dyadic function, then instead of writing `X f Y`, you can also write `Y f⍨ X` which can increase readability and help to avoid parentheses. Try it out [here](https://tryapl.org/?a=.5*%25u23681%F72&run).

Comment: so parens is needed in such situations, if we don't use that uncommon operator.

Comment: Well, let's say parens will be required if you want to keep it readable. If you accept any number of glyphs if only parens could be avoided, then this might also do it (i think ⊣ is only available in Dyalog APL, though): `x*0.5⊣x←1÷2`

Comment: Well, there's always `x*0.5+0×x←1÷2` :-)

Comment: or `2*¯.5`­­­­­

Comment: @ngn I think OP wants a general method rather than a specific answer. The current formula in the post can also be greatly simplified.

Comment: @Adám yeah, `r-.÷x y`

Comment: thanks,  I thought that the notation can write any algebraic formula using only arithmetic functions, but sometimes wrapping some simple operations is nessesary.

Comment: @practronix512 No, APL is basically a better maths. If you want no parentheses, have a look at a [stack-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Here use parentesis () and {} but not in the formula for calc result, only in the function
for construction of function {} and for to get the number in variables in ().

```
  f←{(x y r)←⍵⋄∣-/r×÷x y}
  f 1 2 3
1.5
```